# Generated scaffold's view links are not corresponding correctly to the routes map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a problem with generated view paths. My routes.rb looks like following

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :project_templates do
    resources :awards
  end
...
```

project_template.rb like this

```
class ProjectTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :awards #...

  attr_accessible :user_id #...

  ...
```

award.rb like

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_template
  attr_accessible :tier #..
  ...
```

And generated view links are like this: `awards_path`
This way app does not work and I need to replace all with `project_template_awards_path`

I don't know why generator did this without `project_template` prefix but I ask for you to help me find a way to get around this. Maybe there is some generator command that will add up the missing suffixes to paths? I have to do the same with another class `requirement.rb` and there are views for that too so I hope there is some magic command for solving my issue.

---

`rake routes | grep awards` gives following output:

```
project_template_awards     GET     /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards(.:format)          awards#index
                            POST    /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards(.:format)          awards#create
new_project_template_award  GET     /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards/new(.:format)      awards#new
edit_project_template_award GET     /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards/:id/edit(.:format) awards#edit
project_template_award      GET     /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards/:id(.:format)      awards#show
                            PUT     /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards/:id(.:format)      awards#update
                            DELETE  /project_templates/:project_template_id/awards/:id(.:format)      awards#destroy
```

Comment: What command did you run the generator with? Can you paste it from your shell history?

Comment: `rails generate scaffold Requirement name:string description:text count:integer like_count:integer comment_count:integer project_template:references` is what I ran

Comment: simiar to what I ran for `Awards`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try typing `$ rake routes` in project directory and post there output? Does it still show awards_path for Awards resources?

PS. Controllers have nothing to do here, as you can create route resources without corresponding controllers in app/.

Comment: I'll be updating my question with values given by `$ rake routes | grep awards`

Answer (score 0):

The routes generated are correct. If you want to have this helpers, you can either add this to your route.rb

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :project_templates
  resources :awards
end
```

Or implement helpers like

```
def awards_path(award)
  project_template_awards(awards.project_template, awards)
end
```

More info on [ruby guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)